# Calling and removing instances of a timer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class

In my code, I utilize two timers:

```
var timerScroll:Timer = new Timer();
var timerCollission:Timer = new Timer();
```

First of all... how do I actually call timerScroll/timerCollission to get it's current value...

and for later on...

how do I reset or remove the timer instance from either of them so I can start anew?

I've tried doing like timerScroll.getTimer();... and timerScroll.flash.utils.getTimer();... which I figured wasn't going to work but tried it anyways =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a timer like this:

```
var timerScroll:Timer = new Timer( 2000 ); //2000ms = 2 second interval
timerScroll.start();
timerScroll.stop();
timerScroll.reset();
```

Then, in a separate event listener, apply your callback function to the `TIMER` event.

```
timerScroll.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, myCallback);
function myCallback(e:TimerEvent) {
  trace( timerScroll.currentCount() );
}
```

See the API docs here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html

Comment: +1 cool cool. Thanks for the assistance. timerScroll.currentCount(); gets the actual timer data.